# Cast оператор и шаблонные функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Предположим у меня есть два шаблонных типа: основной, который будет везде использоваться и вспомогательный, для нужд реализации. И я хочу объявить функцию которая принимает основной тип.

```
template<typename T>
struct Usefull;

template<typename T>
struct Helper {
    Helper(T i) : v(i)
    {}

    T v;

    operator Usefull<T>()
    {
        return Usefull<T>(v);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Usefull {
    Usefull(T i) : h(i)
    {}

    Helper<T> h;
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << h.v << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(Usefull<T> b)
{
    b.print();  
}
```

И я хочу использовать это вот так:

```
int main()
{
    Usefull<int> x(42);
    foo(x.h);
}
```

Но возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed: 
'Helper<int>' is not derived from 'Usefull<T>'
```

Использовать `static_cast<Usefull<int>>` не желательно, менять или перегружать foo тоже не охота.
Есть ли какие-то еще способы заставить `Helper<T>` хорошо и неявно преобразовываться в `Useful<T>`?

То есть пользователь не должен знать с чем он работает на самом деле, Useful и Helper для него должны вести себя одинаково. Может здесь можно использовать наследование, но я не приложу ума как это организовать.

Comment: Если явно указать шаблонный аргумент, то вызов функции компилируется   foo<int>(x.h);

Comment: У тебя foo принимает шаблон класса Usefull, а ты передаёшь ей Helper. Передавай объект x, а не x.h.

Comment: В том-то и цель передавать x.h, а не x.

Comment: Ну тогда в функции принимай не Usefull а Helper.

Comment: Нельзя передать в foo Helper хотя бы из-за того, что в Helper нет метода print.

Comment: поправил код, foo - написана пользователем класса, по хорошему ему   должно быть все рано Helper это или Useful

Comment: Если написать foo<int>(x.h); то можно, есть ли способ не указывать тип явно?

Comment: @Алексей Федоров Другой способ - это явно указать приведение типов:  foo( static_cast<Usefull<int>>( x.h ));    Компилятор не будет сам выводить типы, используя оператор преобразования, для шаблонных параметров.

Comment: Из вопроса я понял что "пользователь" это `foo` и он не должен знать что конректно он получил: `Usefull` или `Helper`. А тот кто вызывает `foo` знает о содержании `Usefull` и `Helper` и о требованиях `foo` к своим рагументам а именно наличие функции-члена `print`?

Comment: @Cerbo Да, тот кто вызывает `foo` знает интерфейс `Useful`. Ну в общем я уже понял что хочу странного )),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно примечанию к параграфу №4 в разделе 14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call  стандарта C++

> [ Note: as specified in 14.8.1, **implicit conversions will be performed
>   on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding
>   function parameter if the parameter contains no template-parameters
>   that participate in template argument deduction.** Such conversions are
>   also allowed, in addition to the ones described in the preceding list.
>   —end note ]

В вашем случае соответствующий параметр функции содержит шаблонный параметр, который участвует в выведении шаблонного аргумента. Поэтому вам придется явно указать шаблонный аргумент или явно использовать приведение типов. Например

```
Usefull<int> x(42);

foo<int>(x.h);    
foo( static_cast<Usefull<int>>( x.h ));
```